# Identifying the function of IC chip with part number L6054AAA

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image: IC L6054AAA]Does anybody know the function of this IC chip?

Part number: L6054AAA

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Huatech (西安华泰)](http://www.ht-semi.com/) HTL6054 Li-ion protection IC.

I could only find a screenshot of the first page of the datasheet:

[image]

(Source: [blog.csdn.net](https://blog.csdn.net/zxdzwj/article/details/131012667))